# How to include and or evaluate a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, perl, variable

Problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

x=$1
perl -lne 'print "$x is $_"' $1
```

How to evaluate `$1` in my line no.4 and each time while printing via perl-oneliner, print the evaluated `$1` which is inside single quotes?

Comment: Plese tell us what your expected output is. For example: `$1 is <value of variable $1>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways:

1. Pass the variable as input to the perl one liner:

   ```
   perl -le 'print "\$x is $ARGV[0]"' "$x"
   ```
2. Export the variable and then use perl's `%ENV` hash to print it:

   ```
   export x="$1"
   perl -le 'print "\$x is $ENV{x}"'
   ```
3. Use double quotes for the perl script:

   ```
   perl -le "print \"\\\$x is $x\""
   ```

This is what they would look like in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export x=$1

echo "Approach #1"
perl -le 'print "\$x is $ARGV[0]"' "$x"


echo "Approach #2"
perl -le 'print "\$x is $ENV{x}"' 


echo "Approach #3"
perl -le "print \"\\\$x is $x\""
```

If I save the script aove as `foo.sh` and run it with "foo" as an argument, I get:

```
$ foo.sh foo
Approach #1
$x is foo
Approach #2
$x is foo
Approach #3
$x is foo
```